# How to remove index.php in Magento 1.9 using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have such URL at my Magento website as http://magento.store/about and http://magento.store/index.php/about. I don't need these two pages, I need them to be properly rewrited in .htaccess file. I've tried everything which I could find at StackOverflow but nothing helps. I configured URL-rewrites in configuration using adpanel, used different solutions but the most, I got is to do these redirects but my adpanel doesn't writes any changes to the website's database (I used this solution:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/((?!admin).*) http://www.magento.store/$1
```

In this case it is impossible to change anything in adpanel. The usual solutions such as

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

do not also work. They are ignored as far as I understand. 
How can I solve this issue?

Here is my .htaccess file (the part about the mod_rewrite):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^magento\.store$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.magento.store/$1 [L,R=301]
# redirect pagination
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=1$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.magento.store/$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^pagename$ http://www.magento.store/page-name [L,R=301]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/
#RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+)$ /$1 [R,L]
#RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [R,L]
#RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/(.*)$ /$1
#RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/((?!admin).*) http://magento.store/$1

RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Is it possible that I have some conflicts inf my file?

Comment: Try with default htaccess of magento.

Comment: @urfusion sadly, but I am not able to do this cause these configs are already in use on production server and writen by previous developer. I can't use defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, everybody, for your help. Finally, I made the solution and it is the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/adpanel/
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ http://magento.store/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the part after index.php and redirect the client with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+)$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [R,L]
```

This redirects all requests starting with index.php/ to the URL without index.php. Additionally index.php and index.php/ are redirected to the home page.

Comment: this approach redirected me from http://magento.store/index.php/page/ to http://magento.store/ and suddenly crashed the markup. It also redirects from http://magento.store/page/ to http://magento.store/ Not working for me. What part of my file may conflict with these lines?

Answer (score 1):

Use below .htaccess rule:

```
## index.php on default domain
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/downloader.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.idesignmydrapes.com [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^idesignmydrapes\.com$ [NC]
```